# Cut and paste a threaded frame and not lost its connection to the previous frame

Tags: adobe-indesign

When I cut the second of two threaded frames and then paste it back, it retains its text but loses the connection to the first frame. That is, there are two independent frames then. Is there a way to cut-and-paste a frame in such a way that the connection to the previous frame will be preserved?

By the word "connection" I mean how text flows from one threaded frame to another.

Comment: I don't *think* there is... but maybe someone else has a trick. I generally cut all frames if possible, paste, de-select the frame I want, then delete the other frame(s). Text flow is reset to start at the pasted frame. In order for the *entire* story to still be in the paste, all frames containing the story have to be copy/pasted. Or merely copy the *text*, draw a new frame, and paste the *text* into the new frame. A "retain threaded text" option would be nice though.